# How this blur works

Tags: html, css

Since a few days i was searching for a way to apply a blur easily on an image who could be compatible with all browsers. After i saw a lot of solutions (webkit but not compatible with ie, blur.js and other scripts very long that i didn't sucess to run, algorithme...) i finally found a miraculous way to do it with just a little of html and css : http://jsfiddle.net/jamygolden/yUG5U/2/light/

```
<style>
#svg-image-blur { height: 220px; width: 320px; }
    #svg-image { filter:url(#blur-effect-1); }

</style> 
<svg id="svg-image-blur">
    <image x="10" y="10" id="svg-image" width="300" height="200" xlink:href="http://css-plus.com/examples/2012/03/gaussian-blur/i/fence.jpg" />

    <filter id="blur-effect-1">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" />
    </filter>
</svg>
```

But here is the thing, i don't understand how it works, when i put an `<img>` it doesn't work, i have to do an `<image>` then specify the dimension and replace the `src` by a `xlink:href` or it won't display the image. I can't explain this, is the `<image>` a different tag ? I couldn't find a documentation about it and found the jsfiddle without the explanations of the author.

Anyway i'm trying to set a blur to a background image with a `width: 100%`, the image is not resize : http://jsfiddle.net/fu11q8tc/3/

If someone can explain me i'll be gratefull !

Comment: Considering reading about SVGs, here's a good point of reference: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: SVG is another layer on top of HTML/CSS; it's really a whole different technology, that's why the attributes are different

Comment: `<image>` is SVG, `<img>` is HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) is another layer on top of HTML/CSS; it's really a whole different technology, that's why the elements and attributes are different. As demonstrated by the blurring, it's extremely powerful and there's even an editor called [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) that creates SVG code you can embed in your HTML.

That being said, to stretch your image across the entire with, you need to turn off `preserveAspectRatio` on the image, by setting its value to `none`:

EDIT: added 100% height

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var img = new Image();
  $(img).load(function(){
     var aspectRatio = this.naturalWidth/this.naturalHeight;
     $("#svg-image-blur").css("height", window.innerWidth/aspectRatio);
     console.log(aspectRatio);
  });
  //img.src = "http://css-plus.com/examples/2012/03/gaussian-blur/i/fence.jpg";
  img.src = "http://img4.sizeis.com/photos/banana.jpg";
 });
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#svg-image-blur { width: 100%; overflow: visible; height: 100% }
    #svg-image { filter:url(#blur-effect-1); }

#background-content {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 100%;
    height: 340px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background-content" >     
 <svg id="svg-image-blur">
  <image id="svg-image" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%" id="svg-image" xlink:href="http://img4.sizeis.com/photos/banana.jpg" />
  <filter id="blur-effect-1">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" />
  </filter>
 </svg>  
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know all of this, it's really useful ! It works thanks a lot, i have a last question : is there a way to do a `height: auto` on the image ? It looks bad right now

Comment: No, not exactly. The height image is fix and need to keep the ratio of the width (don't know if i'm clear), that's why it will be easier to just put a `auto` but it seems it's not possible with svg's image tag

Comment: Ok the way it's written now, it will scale to fit what ever dimension it can, while maintaining aspect ratio. In the case of the image you gave, it has a low aspect ratio, so it's not going to fill the screen horizontally. If you want it to stretch to fill the whole screen, you can add back the `preserveAspectRatio="none"` attribute to the image tag

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003155995.htm Documentation of the preserveAspectRatio usage is here

Comment: Yep i wanted it to fill the whole screen in width and you already gave me the way to do it with the `preserveAspectRatio="none"`, once it's done the image fit to the width but it is resize and i have to increase the height and hide the overflow to keep the good dimension.

It would not be a problem if the blur was always on the same image but she is choose by the user and i can't fix a larger height because i can't know what dimension the image he will upload will have

Comment: An exemple is more understable than words : http://jsfiddle.net/fu11q8tc/5/ , now set a bigger height's image tag you'll see what i'm trying to do !

Comment: Does the image need to be a certain height? Sorry, I'm still kind of confused what you're asking for. If you just need it "to look good", you're going to have to put constraints on the images users can upload

Comment: I thinked about constraints but i'm not sure it's the good way, it's for a WP theme and i don't know if i can put maximum dimensions to only one uploader. What i need is to not deform the image when she is display and for this a `height: auto` would do the trick, but i can't apply it in the `<image>` tag

Comment: If you can use JavaScript, then then the above code will emulate the effect of `auto` height, sizing the image to 100% width of the screen and preserving the aspect ratio.

Comment: We're close i think, the auto height is for keep the image ratio not take all the page, what i need exactly (i'll try to be as clear as i can, tell me if you don't understand something) is to upload an image who will be display in a container with a maximum height of 340px, a 100% width and who apply a blur effect on the image, i already can do all of this but  when i do the image is stretched. So i need to set a bigger height and hide the overflow with the parent's container for preserving the image aspect.

Comment: Edited to have it hide the overflow

Comment: It's almost this ! I'll search for the rest of it, thanks so much for your time !